# Issue running slider on server side

Tags: jquery, slider, client

I am using a jQuery Slider. I have used it effectively at client side but have problems when running on server side.

My code for running on client side is:

```
  var a = jQuery.noConflict();
  j(document).ready(function () {
       a('#sliderFrame').nivoSlider();
  });
```

It was working very fine yesterday but today it is not working.
Any help would be great.

Comment: Paid help comes urgently, unpaid help comes when ever it wants.

Comment: You ma also want to change the title and the description because this question has nothing to do with `server side`.

Comment: You dont even know what is server side and what is client side. :/ and no one is working here for you to solve your questions in urgent basis.

Comment: anyways possibly there is an error in loading the `js` file for the slider. check your browser **console** for any error.

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Stuff to do as soon as the DOM is ready. 
    //Use $() w/o colliding with other libs;
    $('#sliderFrame').nivoSlider();
});
```

You don't need to create another object `a`or `j` for using jquery. The above mentioned method is safe to use even if you have multiple javascript libraries.

NOTE: Before using `nivoSlider()` method, make sure you have included the necessary **nivoSlider plugin js file** like this...

```
<script src="path/to/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

please try with below code

```
var a = jQuery.noConflict();
a(document).ready(function () {
   a('#sliderFrame').nivoSlider();
});
```